# Change look of TextBox control

Tags: asp.net, textbox, asp.net-customcontrol

Is there a way I can change the appearance of a `TextBox` from its default look to look like this

[image]

I searched for `creating a custom TextBox` but didnt see anything about changing how it looked.

I have the have the image in a PSD i just didnt know if there was a way to replace the default look with this image

I am new to making websites and just using this for learning purposes so I dont really know where to start

Comment: Rather than custom textbox, check out styling a textbox.

Comment: You will need to learn basic CSS if you are going to write web applications. You apply stlyle via CSS to your webpage to control virtually any visual aspect of a webpage. Then you could have searched CSS ROUNDED CORNERS and you would have learned about appying a border radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CSS to achieve this. What you need to do is to style it. [Here](http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/text-box.php) are some nice examples that could help you.

Here is the one that shows how to add background image:

```
.tb11 {
    background:#FFFFFF url(images/search.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width:230px;
    height:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom asp.net text box control and wrap oob asp.net text box with necessary html (a label or span) and css to style it like the way you want. That control will become reusable and you would be able to use it on any of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy way to do it, just load easy to use bootstrap framework and include the needed file to your project.

Than just add the right class to your control and here it is !

Also, the docs is really complete and simple

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Answer (score 0):

An asp.net `TextBox` is really just an `input` with the `type="text"`.

You can do something like this using stylesheets:

CSS:

```
input[type=text].styled1
{
    background: url(http://myUrl.com/Username.jpg);
    border:0;
    color: gray;
    height: 23px;
    padding-left:10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

XHTML:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="styled1" />
```